# looking for example adal-j to get authentication token

Tags: authentication, adal

My goal is to use Power BI REST api from a webapp and I need
an authentication token from AAD to do so.
I was trying to do the http GET/POST to get the auth code and token in pure java
but it's not working (I get an error 400 when I try to request the token and I cant get any more of a description) so I thought the adalj might be easier. Can someone direct me to a simple example of how to get login user and get auth token?

Thanks for any help

Answer (score 0):

see https://github.com/AzureADSamples/WebApp-GraphAPI-Java for an example showing how to obtain Azure AD tokens for calling an API.